# Webpack-dev-server doesn't hot refresh my client file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack-dev-server, and this is my config:

```
devServer: {
        hot: true,
        contentBase: "dist/"
    },
```

I open in localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server, but when the bundle.js changed, the client just alert that app upload, the page didn't refresh automatically. Why didn't it refresh while it knows the bundle.js has been changed?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: check the console for errors, because there might be a syntax error in your code.

Comment: there isn't any error in console

Comment: could you post your complete webpack.config.js

Comment: thanks a lot, I think may be because that I didn't use react-hot-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack config lacks the [react hot loader](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/).

Updating `bundle.js` is not enough to reloader UI. Reader [react-hot-loader#usage](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#usage) and add it to your web pack config

Comment: Oh, I mean the bundle.js file is the file included in the index.html